# Gmail accessed by third party - deleting important emails - saw one disappear an hour or two ago need recovered

Tags: gmail, hacked

I am in a custody dispute and my ex has in the past verified used spyware - very resourceful.  I noticed on multiple occasions that key emails were deleted - a few times I managed to recover them and they were basically all important to one person only.

I was just looking at an important email a few hours ago, clicked away from it and returned 30 seconds or less later to find it gone and not in any folders,  I checked trash spam etc, and nothing.  I then went to https://support.google.com/mail/workflow/9317561?visit_id=637158719326521936-227949149&rd=1 (Gmail message recovery tool) and made request for recovery.  Returned message to check my email - if found it would reappear within 20 hours.   I remembered that one time before it had taken a few hours, so checked back and still nothing, so I tried again. this time it returned "were sorry no messages to recover, tried again and it returned "we see you have a recovery in progress - continue or start new"  i cant recall but it returned various messages each time, one of which was "something wrong, escalate with google - only came up once - now returning nothing or "we see a search is requested, continue or new"

I think google can search - ie with a person doing it on their end for 30 days - not sure how to escalate though. And yes I have changed PWD multiple times - HELP

Answer (score 1):

Use Google Feedback.

1. Go to gmail.com
2. Click on the gear button then click Send feedback
3. Fill up the form and submit it.

Also post a question on the official Gmail forum -> https://support.google.com/mail/community